# How to Alter all columns at once in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to alter all columns data length at once as there are lot of columns min 10-15 and i want to alter all these columns datalength

```
      alter table states modify id varchar(100);
```

This works but want similar to  (select *...)

```
       alter table states modify * varchar(100);
```

this doesnt work as such is there any other way to do this without manually  writing all columns names

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a solution with USER_TAB_COLS (for the current schema) to generate the ALTER TABLE statements:

```
select 
'alter table ' || table_name || 
' modify ' || column_name || ' varchar2(100);' as code
from user_tab_cols
where table_name='MYTABLE';
```

NB: This generate SQL statements to change *all* columns to VARCHAR2: you need to adapt this script to your needs.

Comment: ahh.,ohk  thanks your solution helped i would delete my answer yes we should never update the database dictionary as its implicit actually i had a demo project so was doing as a part of testing

Comment: On its face, what you propose would also change DATE, TIMESTAMP, NUMBER, etc. to VARCHAR2(100).  I seriously doubt that is what is wanted.  And if it is, I'd _very_ seriously question the premise.